Memory effects from black hole migration in the early universe
Let's say that there is a black hole at the center of a galaxy. When this galaxy is merging with another galaxy, it moves through space. If I am looking at a black hole now, there is a certain region of space that is inaccessible to me, behind the event horizon. But I can look at the black hole after some time when it has moved away a little bit. Now the region of space that was previously inaccessible to me is accessible (this region defined based on the spacetime distance from me and my clock). Some region that was previously accessible to me is not inaccessible. Isn't it magical that a black hole can pass through a region of space-time and the space-time just returns to its normal behavior once the black hole has gone away. The gravitational field (the metric g) and all the other fields can take the same values they could before this region of space was locked up behind the event horizon. Black holes can only isolate a region of space-time but do not alter the nature of the gravitational field once they move on. Isn't that non-trivial? This may be one reason to believe that the interior of the black hole could not be too crazy or it might have scarred that region of space once it passed through.
But maybe it does leave behind some scar. A graduate student at caltech Keefe Mitman presented during his talk The Universe Never Forgets: Pushing Einstein’s Theory to the Limits that they have been working on trying to understand how much plasticity (memory) can gravitational waves leave behind in a certain region of space once they pass through. So, at the least when black holes move through a certain region of space they produce gravitational waves that could leave behind some change in the metric in that space.
Now imagine, early in the universe there were many small primordial black holes. A certain process caused them to move around in a manner that they ended up coaclescing and forming super massive black holes. As they moved through space, they left behind some change in the value of the graviatational field. Could this be one of the ingredients for understanding Dark Matter? For example, I am imagining a spherical shell region with lots of primordial black holes near the shell, all migrating towards the center and coalescing; and I am imagining many such regions in the early universe.
Is something like that possible? The assumption that a passing black holes does not leave behind any scar on the region of space it passed through does not seem trivial to me.

Remember that "the region that was previously behind the event horizon" is not what you think - spacetime consists of events, not places. So the region at later time refers to a particular set of places but at a different time point, not the events that were inside the event horizon when you first looked.  While there may be effects of masses moving around, one should not assume regions exist across time.

@AndersSandberg Right. I guess that was the thing I wasn't being careful about. So what I would be asking is that at a (local collection of) certain spatial (hyper)surface that corresponds to a region of space that the black hole passes through in my reference frame, the gravitational field remain un-influenced, right? As a property of a subspace of the Riemannian manifold spacetime. A property which perhaps holds for any such subspace(surfce) without having to do with the black hole. So, there is or isn't this condition on the values the metric can take in such a subspace of spacetime.

Idealized black holes can be described by certain space-time solutions of Einstein's equations of general relativity. One can rewrite those solutions by choosing different space-time coordinates so that the black hole "moves". One can examine features of this rewritten solution at or near any choice of space-time event. But what one cannot do is to take two events with the same space coordinates and different time coordinates, and to say that the features of the earlier event left some kind of "scar", or had some other causal effect, on the features of the later event,

@LeeMosher That's because it would be like changing your frame of reference, if you were trying to do that, right?

@KaushalTimilsina Your question is based on a wrong premise that there is a region of space inside a black hole separated from the rest of the space by the horizon. This is a common misconception. The inside of a black hole is separated from outside not by space, but by time (in technical terms, the inner radial direction is timelike). The spatial radius of the horizon (in our remote coordinates) is zero and the volume inside a black hole is zero. So, even if space had “memory”, as you are suggesting, still no region of space would change between inside and outside as the black hole moves.


I can look at the black hole after some time when it has moved away a little bit. Now the region of space that was previously inaccessible to me is accessible.

I think your misconception is thinking of black holes as things that are superimposed on top of spacetime and move through it like waves through water. This is incorrect. A black hole is a region of spacetime. If a location in spacetime (an "event") is within the event horizon of a black hole then that is where it is in spacetime - it cannot "reappear". An analogy is that an event that happened one hundred years ago today is always in the past - it cannot suddenly become a future event.

actually, they move exactly "like waves through water" if you see the wave as nothing but a part of the water itself. A better analogy would be a fish, or anything that is not the water.
